# select elements which have a special css attribute with jquery

Tags: css, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="submain">
      .....
      <div class="sub..submain">
      </div>
      .....
   </div>
   <div class="submain">
   </div>
</div>
```

Some of the subelements have the css property `float:right;`, and I dont know how many levels there are.
How can I select all elements with this css property using the selector `$('.main')`?
I have an idea, but I am trying to find an easier way to do it:

```
var elemsArray=[];
   function findNeededChildren(elem){
      var hasChildren = elem.children().length>0?true:false;
      if(hasChildren ){
            $.each(elem.children(),function(){
            if($(this).css('float')=='right')elemsArray.push($(this));
            findNeededChildren($(this));
      });
   }
}
findNeededChildren($('.main'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select elements by an attribute, so you could try

```
$('div[style="float:right"]')
```

This should select all the divs with that attribute. But I am not sure if it will also select something with more than this one style.

Edit:

I just remembered that some people here where I work use classes for this sort of thing. It makes maintainability easier. Make a css rule that says:

`.floatRight {
float:right
}`

Then just assign this class to everything that needs floating. These should be even easier to select.

Comment: Thanks, sorry that i dont notice that in main div and other can be another tag elements like <p> and <h> with this float properties

Comment: If you use the method in my edit it doesn't matter what kind of elements they are. You can cycle through all the elements with a certain class!

Comment: Glad to be helpfull. So, do I get one of those green "answer approved" things? :)

Comment: "But I am not sure if it will also select something with more than this one style." No it won't. Remember that attribute selectors look at HTML attributes. There are no "attributes" in CSS; only properties. When you're querying by the `style` attribute, you're looking at inline styles within the markup.

Comment: Interesting, so this wouldn't work for css which is just declared in a css file? Only stuff which is visible in the browser? Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".main").find("div").each(function(){
     if($(this).css("float") == "right") {
      // This is the required div
     }
   });
})
```

And if you don't know that children of *.main* are divs or other tags then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".main").children().each(function(){
     if($(this).css("float") == "right") {
      // This is the required element with float: right property
     }
   });
})
```

Comment: huh, and when i dont know is there all divs or other tags ? sorry i dont add this info in question. can U help with it.

Comment: yea children is good. and if it will be children in children and .. this cycles of $(this).children().each can be many while sole child dont have another childrens

Comment: It will access all of the children of _.main_ with _float:right_ property regardless of their hierarchy.

Comment: huh, i thought that children its only children of element, and not children of children

Comment: Nah, it will select all of them. Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yea, thanks! all its good, my reputation is too low to Vote Up, sorry

Comment: But you should accept the answer whichever you find more precise to your problem by clicking the accept answer icon.